# beginTransaction y endTransaction manejo de excepciones

Tags: android, android-studio

Ejecuto un insercion sin ningun problema pero cuando vuelvo a ejecutar otra insercion deberia marcarme error por que dentro de esa tabla existe un llave primaria y entonces el error se queda pero en el monitor de android aunque hago el log.e(bla bla bla); es como si se brincara la excepción.

```
public long insertarTipo(List<Tipo> tipo) {
        long n = 1;
        this.openWriteableDB();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (tipo.size() > 0) {
                ContentValues tt = new ContentValues();

                    n = db.insert("Tipo", null, tt);
                }
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Errors.ERROR_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return n;
    }
```

---

Comment: Jorge, imagino que lo que sucede es que no esta insertando el valor y quieres atrapar cuando esto ocurre es así?

Comment: @Elenasys Asi es

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente te comento sobre el método **[insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))**, si esta ocurriendo un error al realizar esta operación no provoca un error.

La [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) indica:

> **insert()**: Retorna el id de la nueva fila insertada o **-1 si un error ha
>   ocurrido.**

Lo que tienes que realizar es validar de esta forma:

```
long n = db.insert("Tipo", null, tt);
if(n == -1){
   //Ocurrio un error! =(.
}else{
   //Inserción exitosa!
}
```

#### En cuanto a tu otro problema: "Primary Key must be unique".

Este error se produce cuando tratas de insertar un registro con una llave primaria (Primary Key) que ya existe!. Revisa cual es el campo que esta definido como Primary Key, pienso que tal vez es "Id", asegura no se inserte un valor que ya existe:

```
 tt.put("Id", tipo.getIdTipo());
```

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys lo implementare de esa forma aunque me sigue lanzando una excepción de tipo SQLiteConstraintException pero no logro cacharla

Comment: @JorgeLuisPiloTorres Revisa mi actualización relacionada a tu error "Primary key must be unique".